# Instance Member Cannot be Used on Type For The Class NSObject

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am getting an error that displays the following message:

> `logoImage` cannot be used on type '`Home`'

I am confused as to why I am receiving this error message. Any help is greatly appreciated!

If you need more information to help answer the question, post a comment and I will get you the information you need.

Thank you in advance!

```
class Home: NSObject {

    var logoImage: [String] = [
         "apple.png",
         "Mango.png",
         "Strawberry.png",
         "Cat.png",
        ]

    class func homeDisplayImage() -> String  {
        for var i = 0; i < 3; i++ {
            return logoImage[i]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java sense; `static` function cannot refer to non-`static` members. It is the same in Swift. Your `logoImage` is non-`static` whilst `homeDisplayImage` is a `static` function.

You would need to either drop the `class` from your function:

```
func homeDisplayImage() -> String  {
for var i = 0; i < 3; i++ {
    return logoImage[i]
}
```

or add a `static` to your `var`:

```
static var logoImage: [String] = [
    "apple.png",
    "Mango.png",
    "Strawberry.png",
    "Cat.png",
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want homeDisplayImage() to be a function of the Home class, take out the word 'class' from in front of it. You're also missing a closing brace. If you use this code it runs with no errors:

```
class Home: NSObject {
    var logoImage: [String] = [
        "apple.png",
        "Mango.png",
        "Strawberry.png",
        "Cat.png",
    ]

    func homeDisplayImage() -> String  {
        for var i = 0; i < 3; i++ {
            return logoImage[i]
        }
    }
}
```